# How can I take a screenshot of the entire screen in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, screenshot, multiple-monitors

How can I take a screenshot of one monitor / screen in Node JS? What libraries do I need and how do I use them? It needs to be able to successfully write to a file the contents of the entire monitor.

I can't seem to find anything but how to take screenshots of webpages, or specific windows. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @jox No, I'm trying to simply take a screenshot, and save it to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the [`screenshot-desktop` npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenshot-desktop). It's cross platform (Linux, Mac, Windows) and can save directly to a file.

Install:

```
$ npm install --save screenshot-desktop
```

Use:

```
const screenshot = require('screenshot-desktop')

screenshot({ filename: 'shot.jpg' }).then((imgPath) => {
  // imgPath: absolute path to screenshot
  // created in current working directory named shot.png
});

// absolute paths work too. so do pngs
screenshot({ filename: '/Users/brian/Desktop/demo.png' })
```